# Swagger2 - No handler found for GET

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have developed one API in `Spring boot`. where I used **Swagger2** for easiness & `technical` doc purposefully.
Now, I am running through an issue which is mainly cause on our whole API.
It's Frequently printing a logs. it's around in 1-min. 2-5 MB logs are created. which is absolutely not acceptable. Due to the below mentioned error.

I strongly believe, it's because of Swagger UI configuration. it's appearing.

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /null/swagger-resources/configuration/security

org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /null/swagger-resources

org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui
```

I have already configured to **bypassed** the following `endpoints` from my "**`Authentication/Authorization`**" `validation` checks.

```
1. /swagger-ui.html
2. /v2/api-docs
3. /swagger-resources/configuration/ui
4. /swagger-resources
5. /swagger-resources/configuration/security
```

Question is, why it's internally calls endpoints which are starting with `/null` prefix(see the above mentioned 3-erroneous statements which are printing in my logs)

*Surplice! & Interesting!* things for me is, it's happening(*causing*) in only one of my `environment`(`DEV, TEST, PROD`). Whereas in other `environment`, it works very well without throwing any such kind of `errors`.

**NOTE** - I have enabled `swagger` only in `DEV & LOCAL env.` only. May be due to this reason, it's not giving any `error` in `TEST & PROD` respectively. Again I am not sure what's wrong going on.

Even, In my Local also not giving any errors!

I am using following maven dependencies to enable swagger are,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciable!!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @JoseMartinez Yeah... Actually, some one was attacked on my API & I have added it(ID Address) into my black-list from server side. so now there is no more error...

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to swagger 3 solved the problem for me. This [link](https://medium.com/@hala3k/setting-up-swagger-3-with-spring-boot-2-a7c1c3151545?sk=4a54b60572b200d4a2ea17bd54906d29) might be useful.